# Add to Calendar Button Plugin and Shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I recently installed the Wordpress Plugin called "Add to Calendar" and trying to incorporate the code which generates the button into an event shortcode I created.

Their supplied code for the button looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <add-to-calendar-button
    name="title"
    startDate="2023-05-11"
    startTime="10:15"
    endTime="23:30"
    timeZone="America/Los_Angeles"
    description=""
    options="'Apple','Google','iCal','Outlook.com','Yahoo'"
    buttonsList
    hideTextLabelButton
    buttonStyle="round"
    lightMode="bodyScheme"
    ></add-to-calendar-button>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is populate the different field of this code with information from the custom post type. For example pull the post title into the name field, looking something like this:

```
    name="Post Title"
```

Here's my entire coding for the shortcode if it helps:

```
<?php

add_shortcode( 'Calendar', 'calendar' );

function calendar( $atts, $shrt_content = null ) {
    
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
'category' => ''
), $atts, 'calendar');

$categories  = ! empty( $atts['category'] ) ? explode( ',' , $atts['category'] ) : '';

extract( $atts );   

$query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'category_name'     => 'private',
    'tax_query'         => array( array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'operator'  => 'AND',
                'terms'     => $categories
            ) )
);

$post_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
$number_of_events = $events_query->found_posts;

ob_start();

// If post is there
if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

<?php while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>
                    
        <?php
        $monthStart = get_field('event_date');
        $formatMonthStart = date("M", strtotime($monthStart));
        $dateStart = get_field('event_date');
        $formatDateStart = date("j", strtotime($dateStart));    
        $yearStart = get_field('event_date');
        $formatYearStart = date("y", strtotime($yearStart));    
        ?>

<div id="eventDetails" >
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<p>     
<?php echo the_field('event_date'); ?>          
<?php $value = get_field( "event_date" );
if( $value ) { echo ' - ' . get_field('event_date') .' ';
} else { echo ''; } ?>
</p>
        
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        
<html>
    <add-to-calendar-button
        name="title"
        startDate="2023-05-11"
        startTime="10:15"
        endTime="23:30"
        timeZone="America/Los_Angeles"
        description=""
        options="'Apple','Google','iCal','Outlook.com'"
        buttonsList
        hideTextLabelButton
        buttonStyle="round"
        lightMode="bodyScheme"
    ></add-to-calendar-button>
</html>
                    
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php 
}

$retVal = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $retVal; 
}
```

The fields I'm looking to populate are as follows: name, startDate, startTime, endTime and description

I would think this is doable, but shortcodes are still pretty new for me.

Additionally, I've tried something like this:

```
name=<?php echo the_title(); ?>
```

Which partially works, when clicking on the button - the appropriate calendar opens, but the only thing that shows up in the event name is the 1st word, anything after a space does not show up.

Comment: To get this started: The last step (using `<php echo the_title(); ?>` should work, if you add quotes!
-> `<php echo '"' . the_title() . '"'; ?>`

Comment: updated the one line to read, but the results are the same, first word of the title shows, then nothing after the space. Seems like the space is breaking the full title.

    name=<? php echo ‘”‘ . the_title() . ‘”‘; ?>

Comment: To be honest, the provided code snippet looks a little broken in many ways. Hard to tell where to start fixing. Let's try to get the debug option in and your test page working, so I can have a better look. Since this discussion is present on multiple boards, I would take next steps at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/event-details-generated-off-custom-post-type-fields/#post-16746222

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the information you provided on the other board, which you linked.